# json encode new Date javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have software that is waiting for such an input:

```
var calEvents = [
    {"name":"2440 Százhalombatta, Bláthy Ottó utca 10","start":new Date('2019-10-20'),"end":new Date('2019-10-20'),"summary":"Ez egy teszt üzenet"},
    {"name":"2440 Százhalombatta, Bláthy Ottó utca 10","start":new Date('2019-10-22'),"end":new Date('2019-10-22'),"summary":"Ez egy teszt üzenet"},
];
```

My code is:

```
<?php
$return_arr = array();
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM munkalap"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['name'] = $row['cim'];
$row_array['start'] = "new Date("2019-10-20")";
 $row_array['end'] = "new Date("2019-10-20")";
    $row_array['summary'] = $row['cim'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

My mistake is that I cannot pass the date in this format:

```
new Date("2019-10-20")
```

Comment: `new Date("2019-10-20")` isn't valid JSON - you can pass the date as a string and then decode it in Javascript.

Comment: the software you have is expecting **invalid** json and should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. The value of `start` and `end` in PHP you are processing is a string, not a JS `Date()` object. You can't execute such a JS code in PHP.

But you can process only date in PHP and convert it to `Date()` object in JS by the following way:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$return_arr = array();
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM munkalap");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['name'] = $row['cim'];
    $row_array['start'] = '2019-10-20';
    $row_array['end'] = '2019-10-20';
    $row_array['summary'] = $row['cim'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var calEvents = [
    {"name":"2440 Százhalombatta, Bláthy Ottó utca 10","start":'2019-10-20',"end":'2019-10-20',"summary":"Ez egy teszt üzenet"},
    {"name":"2440 Százhalombatta, Bláthy Ottó utca 10","start":'2019-10-22',"end":'2019-10-22',"summary":"Ez egy teszt üzenet"},
];

calEvents = calEvents.map(i => {
    i.start = new Date(i.start)
    i.end = new Date(i.end)
    return i;
})
```

**I've suggestion for you:**

- Don't use `mysql`, because it is deprecated from PHP version 5.6
- Alternatively you can use [**mysqli_***](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: more appropriate, well descriptive.+1

Comment: `mysql_*` is not only deprecated it has been removed altogether.

Comment: Yes! it is removed from PHP 7.